# How to get functions to run correctly when implemented into a switch case statement

Tags: c

UPDATE: The issue seems to be related to the scanf("%[^\n]s", message); line because when the [^\n] is removed the function works but does not consider whitespace. The function alone works when called in main alone but does not print correctly with the menu.

I have two separate functions which have proven to work correctly when simply called in main, however I need to combine all these functions into one code, and call them via a switch case menu for the user. When I implement this, the individual codes do not work the same as there is a printing error. The code is for rotation ciphers, and one function has been included with the switch case menu for the user. When the encryptRK() function is called alone (i.e. without the switch case menu) it correctly prints the first line and then takes the user input and provides the correct output. When put in this singular code with the user menu in main, it no longer works and prints "Enter a message to encrypt: Enter rotation key:" all on one line and will not accept an input to encrypt, even when \n is entered in the printf statement. Why will this code not work with the menu if it works when called alone?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char encryptRK(char character, int key); 
char decryptRK(char charcter, int key); 

int main() {
char character;
int key;

printf("Please select an option: \n");\
printf("a) Encrypt a message using rotation cipher with key given\n");
printf("b) Decrypt a message using rotation cipher with key given\n");
printf("c) Encrypt a message using substitution cipher with key given\n");
printf("d) Decrypt a message using substitution cipher with key given\n");
printf("e) Decrypt a message using rotation cipher given text only\n");
printf("f) Decrypt a message using substitution cipher given text only\n");

char c;
scanf("%c", &c);

while(c > 'a' || c < 'f'){
    switch(c){
        case 'a': encryptRK(character, key);
            break;
        case 'b': decryptRK(character, key);
            break;
        /*case 'c': encryptSK(character, key);
            break;
        case 'd': decryptSK(character, key);
            break;
        case 'e': decryptR(character);
            break;
        case 'f': decryptS(character);
            break;*/
        default: printf("Unknown option %c\nPlease enter a, b, c, d, e or f\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

```
// Case 'a': Function for encryptRK() 

char encryptRK(char character, int key){

char message[100];
int i;

printf("Enter a message to encrypt: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", message);

printf("Enter rotation key: ");
scanf("%d", &key); 

for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i){
    character = message[i];

    if(character >= 'a' && character <= 'z'){
        character = character - 32;
        character = character + key;

        if(character > 'Z'){
            character = character - 26;
        }
    }

    else if(character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z'){
        character = (character + key);

        if(character > 'Z'){
              character = character - 26;
           }
    }

    message[i] = character;
}

printf("Encrypted message: %s", message);
//return message;
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning any value to the `character` variable when it is passed to the function.

Comment: Additionally, you probably want `while(c > 'a' && c < 'f')` instead of  `while(c > 'a' || c < 'f')`

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried both of these but neither change the output

Answer (score -1):

You have check your character which is grater than a and less then f on while loop. Try to use a>= & <=f
check it out.

Comment: Again, unfortunately this does not change the printed output

Comment: while(c >= 'a' || c <= 'f')